# Magento 1.9. Путь к файлу обработчику «Наличие на складе»

Tags: magento

На странице редактирования товара в секции «Склад» есть правило для товара «Наличие на складе».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если на основном складе (на скрине — 1), поставить 0, а в селекте выбрать «в наличии», то после сохранения наличие на складе — нет в наличии. Мне нужно что бы это правило еще и проверяло кастомные склады (2, 3...).

Вопрос: где лежит файл обработчик, который проверяет количество на складе (1) и ставит правило «нет в наличии»?